# CSS animation stlye is not working on div element inside flexbox

Tags: html, css

Can someone please review the following block of code and tell me why the animation on the image div and info div are not working.
this is the html file for the about page. (i had enclosed the block content in a div and given it position relative)

```
{%extends 'layout.html' %}
{%block content %}
```

```css
.about {
  align-items: center;
  top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#image {
  animation-name: image2;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.image-file {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

#info {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: info2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: info2;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes image2 {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes info2 {
  0% {
    right: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes info2 {
  0% {
    right: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='head1'>
  <h class='head'>Welcome to the Home page</h>
</div>
<div class='about'>
  <div id='image'>
    <image class='image-file' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' alt='nelson'>
  </div>
  <div id='info'>
    <h class='head'>About me</h>
    <p class='text'>I am a web developer specialized in vanilla css,<br> html and flask. <br>But i am developing further.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, open the dev tools, locate the div image, and see the styles info.

You will see something like this

[image: screen capture]

Notice that left is grayed. Now, hover on the "i" circle. You will see a message stating "left has no effect because the element is not positioned".

So, this is your problem

```css
.about {
  align-items: center;
  top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#image {
  animation-name: image2;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;  /* added */
}

.image-file {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

#info {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: info2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: info2;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;  /* added */
}

@keyframes image2 {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes info2 {
  0% {
    right: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes info2 {
  0% {
    right: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='head1'>
  <h class='head'>Welcome to the Home page</h>
</div>
<div class='about'>
  <div id='image'>
    <image class='image-file' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' alt='nelson'>
  </div>
  <div id='info'>
    <h class='head'>About me</h>
    <p class='text'>I am a web developer specialized in vanilla css,<br> html and flask. <br>But i am developing further.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this works...thanks a bunch it had bothered me alot

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
#image {   position:absolute; }
```